# Long creation time using conda env create -f environment.yml

Tags: conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

I am trying to create an environment, but the process has been stuck at `Installing pip dependencies` for several hours. Here is my input:

```
$ conda env create -f environment.yml
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                                                                                 
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                                      
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                                      
Executing transaction: done                                                                                                                      
Installing pip dependencies: |
```

Here is the `environment.yml` file:

```
name: cfd
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - ca-certificates=2021.10.26=h06a4308_2
  - certifi=2021.10.8=py38h06a4308_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libstdcxx-ng
  - ncurses=6.3=h7f8727e_2
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h7f8727e_0
  - pip=21.2.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.12=h12debd9_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.12.0
    - asttokens==2.0.5
    - astunparse==1.6.3
    - attrs==21.2.0
    - backcall==0.2.0
    - black==22.1.0
    - cachetools==4.2.4
    - charset-normalizer==2.0.9
    - chex==0.1.3
    - click==8.0.4
    - cloudpickle==2.0.0
    - cycler==0.11.0
    - dask==2022.2.0
    - debugpy==1.5.1
    - decorator==5.1.1
    - dill==0.3.4
    - dm-haiku==0.0.5
    - dm-tree==0.1.6
    - einops==0.3.2
    - entrypoints==0.4
    - execnet==1.9.0
    - executing==0.8.2
    - flatbuffers==1.12
    - flax==0.4.2
    - fonttools==4.28.3
    - future==0.18.2
    - gast==0.4.0
    - gin-config==0.5.0
    - google-auth==2.3.3
    - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
    - google-pasta==0.2.0
    - googleapis-common-protos==1.54.0
    - grpcio==1.34.1
    - h5py==3.1.0
    - idna==3.3
    - imageio==2.13.3
    - importlib-metadata==4.8.2
    - importlib-resources==5.4.0
    - iniconfig==1.1.1
    - ipykernel==6.9.1
    - ipython==8.0.1
    - jedi==0.18.1
    - jmp==0.0.2
    - jupyter-client==7.1.2
    - jupyter-core==4.9.2
    - keras-nightly
    - keras-preprocessing
    - kiwisolver==1.3.2
    - locket==0.2.1
    - markdown==3.3.6
    - matplotlib==3.5.0
    - matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
    - msgpack==1.0.3
    - mypy-extensions==0.4.3
    - nest-asyncio==1.5.4
    - networkx==2.6.3
    - nonechucks==0.4.2
    - numpy==1.19.5
    - oauthlib==3.1.1
    - opt-einsum==3.3.0
    - optax==0.1.2
    - packaging==21.3
    - pandas==1.3.4
    - parso==0.8.3
    - partd==1.2.0
    - pathspec==0.9.0
    - pexpect==4.8.0
    - pickleshare==0.7.5
    - pillow==8.4.0
    - platformdirs==2.5.1
    - pluggy==1.0.0
    - promise==2.3
    - prompt-toolkit==3.0.28
    - protobuf==3.19.1
    - ptyprocess==0.7.0
    - pure-eval==0.2.2
    - py==1.11.0
    - pyasn1==0.4.8
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pygments==2.11.2
    - pyparsing==3.0.6
    - pytest==6.2.5
    - pytest-forked==1.4.0
    - pytest-xdist==2.5.0
    - python-dateutil==2.8.2
    - pytz==2021.3
    - pywavelets==1.2.0
    - pyyaml==6.0
    - pyzmq==22.3.0
    - requests==2.26.0
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
    - rsa==4.8
    - scikit-image==0.19.0
    - scipy==1.7.3
    - seaborn==0.11.2
    - setuptools-scm==6.3.2
    - six==1.15.0
    - stack-data==0.2.0
    - tabulate==0.8.9
    - tensorboard
    - tensorboard-data-server
    - tensorboard-plugin-wit
    - tensorflow
    - tensorflow-datasets
    - tensorflow-estimator
    - tensorflow-metadata
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - tifffile==2021.11.2
    - toml==0.10.2
    - tomli==1.2.2
    - toolz==0.11.2
    - torch==1.10.0
    - tornado==6.1
    - tqdm==4.62.3
    - traitlets==5.1.1
    - tree-math==0.1.0
    - typing-extensions==4.2.0
    - urllib3==1.26.7
    - wcwidth==0.2.5
    - werkzeug==2.0.2
    - wrapt==1.12.1
    - xarray==0.20.2
    - zipp==3.6.0
```

Comment: Should I try deleting everything from `-pip:` till the bottom and manually pip installing the packages? Would I have to delete the environment first?